# Get URL from web page using IMPORTXML

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, importxml

Though I am new to web scraping, but I have a hand on experience of web scraping using VBA (Excel) I am facing the following problem:

I have tried all methods (`ImportXML`, `ImportHTMP`, `ImportData`, etc.) for importing data from web-page but getting `#N/A` error. URL from which I am trying to import is
[Link](https://kimcartoon.to/Cartoon/Avatar-The-Last-Airbender-Season-01) and the formula is as following (C3, contains a link):

```
=importXML(C3,"//td/a/@href")
```

From this method, I want to import all links available in a table (I want to get cartoon episodes' URL from web-page of Cartoon series).

Please help me to figure out the mistake I am performing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(" ", 
 "https://kimcartoon.to"&QUERY(IMPORTXML(C3, "//a/@href"), 
 "select Col1 where Col1 contains '"&("pisode")&"' ")), " ")))
```

[image]

Comment: I have already tried this kind of trick with Filter formula (using 'Cartoon' keyword instead of 'pisode'); but my concern is **How to deal with table (or 'td' tag) using ImportXML formula?**. However, thank you so much for your quick reply.

Comment: @SaadBinKhalid here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7B4tPczv-H8

Comment: @SaadBinKhalid and: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pwZ44kAeiOo